# Getting data out of a Future in Scala

Tags: scala, future

I've a `Future[List[Person]]`[1] and I want to get the `List[Person]` from it. How can I do it ?

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
val futPersons : Future[List[Person]] = ....
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

```
futPersons.map { personList =>
  ....
}
```

This map returns another `Future` composed with whatever you return from the map. The map will execute only if the future completes successfully. If you need to handle failure you can use onComplete

```
futPersons.onComplete {
  case Success(personList) => ...
  case Failure(exception)  =>  ... 
}
```

Or you can wait for the future to complete (this is blocking):

```
val personList: List[Person] = Await.result(futPersons, 1 minutes)
```

Comment: note that `Await` is blocking so it shouldn't be used. Best option is to use `future composition`.

Comment: @goral It is mentioned as blocking. Sure there are cases where one can wait for a futures to complete.

Answer (score 3):

Blocking way (pauses your thread until you get the value back) using [`Await.result`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await%24):

```
scala.concurrent.Await.result(futPersons, timeout)
```

Or, using a callback with [`onSuccess`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future):

```
futPersons onSuccess {
    case persons => // do something with persons
}
```