# Scala_Spark_DataFrame using Future method

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to solve a scenario in which I am reading the `HiveContext` as `Future` using Scala. But I am unable to print the returned dataframe.

My code:

```
val f: Future[DataFrame] = Future{hive.sql("select * from test1.emp")}
```

How to get the `DataFrame` from the `Future[DataFrame]` object?

Comment: Thanks for the link.But here in this dataframe. I always getting the schema  as the o/p ,not the dataframe exact o/p

Comment: `f.onComplete { case Success(v) => v.show }`

Comment: Thanks ..This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

`val f: Future[DataFrame] = Future{hive.sql("select * from test1.emp")}.foreach(df => df.show())`

So basically like in the answers already posted here - [Getting data out of a Future in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028114/getting-data-out-of-a-future-in-scala) , you can do all you operations on a DataFrame in a map function. `df.show()` can be replaced with any other command.

Comment: Thnaks for the update.Here in this case,Error type mismatch will be getting as an error.-Found :unit but required : Dataframe

Comment: My bad, should be foreach isntead of map if your function has just to print things.